# RIS files suddenly uploading irregularly to R studio?

Tags: r, dataframe, import

I've been uploading RIS files to R studio frequently as part of a systematic review. Typically when I upload these files (exporting with full records from Web of Science to EndNote), the result is a dataframe with 126 variables (which include data from each articles full record).

So far, the uploads have included 1000 publications as I have been analyzing the success of different search string iterations. But now, I have settled on a final iteration and tried to upload a RIS file of 4,191 publications in the same manner. The resulting dataframe contains 282 variables (more than double the original format) and only 4160 observations (where the n amount of publications = 4,191).

Is the file type too big to read into R Studio correctly? Do I need to update R Studio? Any advice will be welcome! Thanks.

So far, I've used Web of Science to find publications. For trial iterations, I export the full record of the first 1000 results to my EndNote library and house them in a group. From there, I export the RIS file to my working environment and import from R. I have been using the LitSearchr package to analyze my RIS files. I've imported all the files in the same format:

```
final_results<-import_results(file='finalsearch_wos.txt').
```

All files return a dataframe of 1004 observations (not sure where the extra 4 observations come from) and 126 variables for the trial iterations. But for my final search (4,191 publications), the dataframe contains 4,160 observations and 282 variables.

Comment: You are reading files into R - not RStudio - RStudio is just the interface to R. It's difficult to help without example data - perhaps you could provide a link to a RIS file? One culprit might be special characters or issues with character encoding.

Comment: the file "finalsearch_wos" is the problem child and "thirdsearch_wos" works like normal! If the link is restricted, let me know: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1l6a5tsTXQh6qMP5b_CrEynYWetC8Q1Px?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry my file sharing is limited on VPN